# How to fix submit button activation error?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

Now the button is activated if one of the fields is valid.

[image]

As I understand it, it is necessary to select all errors, and if there are more than 1 errors - disabled

Code validation

```js
var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.validate');
for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
  forms[i].setAttribute('novalidate', true);
  forms[i].lastElementChild.setAttribute('disabled', true);
}

// function has error
var hasError = function(field) {

  if (field.disabled || field.type === 'file' || field.type === 'reset' || field.type === 'submit' || field.type === 'button') return;

  var validity = field.validity;

  if (validity.valid) {
    return;
  }

  if (validity.valueMissing) {
    return 'This is a required field';
  }

  if (validity.typeMismatch) {

    // URL
    if (field.type === 'url') {
      return 'There should be a link';
    }

  }

  if (validity.tooShort) {
    return 'Must be from ' + field.getAttribute('minLength') + ' to ' + field.getAttribute('maxLength') + ' characters';
  }

  if (validity.tooLong) {
    return 'Must be from ' + field.getAttribute('minLength') + ' to ' + field.getAttribute('maxLength') + ' characters';
  }

  return 'Error';

};

// function show error
var showError = function(field, error) {

  field.classList.add('error');

  var id = field.id || field.name;
  if (!id) return;

  var message = field.form.querySelector('.error-message#error-for-' + id);
  if (!message) {
    message = document.createElement('div');
    message.className = 'error-message';
    message.id = 'error-for-' + id;

    field.parentNode.insertBefore(message, field.nextSibling);

  }

  field.setAttribute('aria-describedby', 'error-for-' + id);

  message.innerHTML = error;

  message.style.display = 'block';
  message.style.visibility = 'visible';

};

// function remove error
var removeError = function(field) {

  field.classList.remove('error');

  field.removeAttribute('aria-describedby');

  var id = field.id || field.name;
  if (!id) return;


  var message = field.form.querySelector('.error-message#error-for-' + id + '');
  if (!message) return;

  message.innerHTML = '';
  message.style.display = 'none';
  message.style.visibility = 'hidden';

};


// function check field
function checkInput(event) {

  if (!event.target.form.classList.contains('validate')) return;

  var error = hasError(event.target);

  if (error) {
    event.target.parentElement.parentElement.lastElementChild.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    showError(event.target, error);
    return;
  }

  removeError(event.target);
  event.target.parentElement.parentElement.lastElementChild.removeAttribute('disabled');

}


// function check fields
function validationForm(event) {

  if (!event.target.classList.contains('validate')) return;

  var fields = event.target.elements;

  var error, hasErrors;
  for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    error = hasError(fields[i]);
    if (error) {
      showError(fields[i], error);
      if (!hasErrors) {
        hasErrors = fields[i];
      }
    }
  }

  if (hasErrors) {
    event.preventDefault();
    hasErrors.focus();
  }

}

document.addEventListener('input', checkInput);
document.addEventListener('submit', validationForm);
```

```css
input {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  width: 100%;
}

.button[disabled],
.button[disabled]:active,
.button[disabled]:focus,
.button[disabled]:hover {
  border-color: #ccc;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.button {
  background-color: #0088cc;
  border: 1px solid #0088cc;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.9375em;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-right: 0.3125em;
  margin-bottom: 0.3125em;
  padding: 0.5em 0.6875em;
  width: auto;
}

.button:active,
.button:focus,
.button:hover {
  background-color: #005580;
  border-color: #005580;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}    


/**
* Errors
*/

.error {
  border-color: red;
}

.error-message {
  color: red;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<form class="validate">
  <div>
    <input type="text" minlength="3" maxlength="40" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="url" name="url" pattern="^(?:(?:https?|HTTPS?|ftp|FTP):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-zA-Z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-zA-Z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-zA-Z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-zA-Z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,}))\.?)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\S*)?$"
      placeholder="Enter url" required>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">
</form>

<br>

<form class="validate">
  <div>
    <input type="user" minlength="4" maxlength="40" id="user" placeholder="Enter user" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="position" minlength="5" maxlength="50" id="position" placeholder="Enter position" required>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I guess this is the problem part of the code

```
// function check field
function checkInput(event) {

  if (!event.target.form.classList.contains('validate')) return;

  var error = hasError(event.target);

  if (error) {
  event.target.parentElement.parentElement.lastElementChild.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    showError(event.target, error);
    return;     
  }

  removeError(event.target);
  event.target.parentElement.parentElement.lastElementChild.removeAttribute('disabled');

}
```

I expect the button to activate only if both fields have passed validation.
But now the button is activated if one of the fields is valid

Comment: So much code. Why not just add required to the fields and give them a type?

Comment: For self-education purposes, I would like to do using javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to update your check function. Current function is just Validating input that you are changing as you have added change input listener. you would need to add loop that Validate other fields for error.

```
// function check field
function checkInput(event) {

  if (!event.target.form.classList.contains('validate')) return;

  var error = hasError(event.target);

  if (error) {
    event.target.parentElement.parentElement.lastElementChild.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    showError(event.target, error);
    return;
  }

  //To Check All fields If There is still an error
  var fields = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.elements;
  for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    error = hasError(fields[i]);
    if (error) {
      removeError(event.target);
      event.target.parentElement.parentElement.lastElementChild.setAttribute('disabled', true);
      return;
    }
  }

  removeError(event.target);
  event.target.parentElement.parentElement.lastElementChild.removeAttribute('disabled');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

```js
var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.validate');
for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
  forms[i].setAttribute('novalidate', true);
  forms[i].lastElementChild.setAttribute('disabled', true);
}

// function has error
var hasError = function(field) {

  if (field.disabled || field.type === 'file' || field.type === 'reset' || field.type === 'submit' || field.type === 'button') return;

  var validity = field.validity;

  if (validity.valid) {
    return;
  }

  if (validity.valueMissing) {
    return 'This is a required field';
  }

  if (validity.typeMismatch) {

    // URL
    if (field.type === 'url') {
      return 'There should be a link';
    }

  }

  if (validity.tooShort) {
    return 'Must be from ' + field.getAttribute('minLength') + ' to ' + field.getAttribute('maxLength') + ' characters';
  }

  if (validity.tooLong) {
    return 'Must be from ' + field.getAttribute('minLength') + ' to ' + field.getAttribute('maxLength') + ' characters';
  }

  return 'Error';

};

// function show error
var showError = function(field, error) {

  field.classList.add('error');

  var id = field.id || field.name;
  if (!id) return;

  var message = field.form.querySelector('.error-message#error-for-' + id);
  if (!message) {
    message = document.createElement('div');
    message.className = 'error-message';
    message.id = 'error-for-' + id;

    field.parentNode.insertBefore(message, field.nextSibling);

  }

  field.setAttribute('aria-describedby', 'error-for-' + id);

  message.innerHTML = error;

  message.style.display = 'block';
  message.style.visibility = 'visible';

};

// function remove error
var removeError = function(field) {

  field.classList.remove('error');

  field.removeAttribute('aria-describedby');

  var id = field.id || field.name;
  if (!id) return;


  var message = field.form.querySelector('.error-message#error-for-' + id + '');
  if (!message) return;

  message.innerHTML = '';
  message.style.display = 'none';
  message.style.visibility = 'hidden';

};


// function check field
function checkInput(event) {

  if (!event.target.form.classList.contains('validate')) return;

  var error = hasError(event.target);

  if (error) {
    event.target.parentElement.parentElement.lastElementChild.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    showError(event.target, error);
    return;
  }

  //To Check All fields If There is still an error
  var fields = event.target.parentElement.parentElement.elements;
  for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    error = hasError(fields[i]);
    if (error) {
      removeError(event.target);
      event.target.parentElement.parentElement.lastElementChild.setAttribute('disabled', true);
      return;
    }
  }

  removeError(event.target);
  event.target.parentElement.parentElement.lastElementChild.removeAttribute('disabled');

}

// function check fields
function validationForm(event) {

  if (!event.target.classList.contains('validate')) return;

  var fields = event.target.elements;

  var error, hasErrors;
  for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    error = hasError(fields[i]);
    if (error) {
      showError(fields[i], error);
      if (!hasErrors) {
        hasErrors = fields[i];
      }
    }
  }

  if (hasErrors) {
    event.preventDefault();
    hasErrors.focus();
  }

}

document.addEventListener('input', checkInput);
document.addEventListener('submit', validationForm);
```

```css
input {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  width: 100%;
}

.button[disabled],
.button[disabled]:active,
.button[disabled]:focus,
.button[disabled]:hover {
  border-color: #ccc;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.button {
  background-color: #0088cc;
  border: 1px solid #0088cc;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.9375em;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-right: 0.3125em;
  margin-bottom: 0.3125em;
  padding: 0.5em 0.6875em;
  width: auto;
}

.button:active,
.button:focus,
.button:hover {
  background-color: #005580;
  border-color: #005580;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}    


/**
* Errors
*/

.error {
  border-color: red;
}

.error-message {
  color: red;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<form class="validate">
  <div>
    <input type="text" minlength="3" maxlength="40" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="url" name="url" pattern="^(?:(?:https?|HTTPS?|ftp|FTP):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-zA-Z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-zA-Z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-zA-Z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-zA-Z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,}))\.?)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:[/?#]\S*)?$"
      placeholder="Enter url" required>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">
</form>

<br>

<form class="validate">
  <div>
    <input type="user" minlength="4" maxlength="40" id="user" placeholder="Enter user" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="position" minlength="5" maxlength="50" id="position" placeholder="Enter position" required>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You are Most Welcome

Answer (score 0):

The reason for it not to work as expected is that you remove the disabled state if there's no error by calling
`event.target.parentElement.parentElement.lastElementChild.removeAttribute('disabled');`
but don't add the Attribute `disabled` if there is an error.
So if you leave the `name` input blank but add e.g. `http://example.com` the button is enabled as the URL triggered the `removeAttribute()` function.
As mplungjan suggested it might be better to just use `required` attribute.